# $_POST sql перезагрузка страницы

Tags: php, http

Имеется форма добавления записей в базу данных

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Введите сюда..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

и обработчик этой формы

```
if(!empty($text)) {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO table (id,text) VALUES (NULL,$text)");
}
```

После обновления страницы данный скрипт повторно выполняет этот запрос, как сделать так что после нажатия кнопки ok скрипт записывал информацию в бд, и после этого сбрасывал, что бы после обновления страницы скрипт уже не выполнялся? Запрос к базе данных должен выполняться только один раз - после нажатия кнопки "Ок".

Answer (score 1):

После добавления данных тебе нужно послать браузеру заголовок `location`, в котором указать адрес страницы, с которой посылались данные.

```
header("Location: <тут адрес>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```